# Advertencia al subir imagen a proyecto con Unity5

Tags: unity, unity2d

Al cargar una imagen a un proyecto en unity5 esta imagen devuelve una advertencia a la hora de compilar en proyecto.

> Only pot textures can be compressed to etc1 format

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Only pot textures can be compressed to etc1 format

Quiere decir que en nuestro formato de imagen no se esta ejecutando la compresión.

**Como solucionamos esto? muy sencillo**

Solo necesita usar potencia de 2 en nuestra imagen: por ejemplo,**128x128, 256x256, 512x512** píxeles, luego el sprite (2D y UI) se comprimirá automáticamente.